# omnibus or source - can't decide which one to use for gitllab backup/restore

Tags: linux, git, github, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu server running gitlab server.
I need to perform daily backup/restore of my gitlab.

Which method should I prefer: omnibus or from source?
How can I check weather GitLab is installed via omnibus or from source?

Answer (score 0):

Source or Omnibus, you will have access to the [**same backup procedure**](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md), which will create an archive file that contains the database, all repositories and all attachments.

That means you are saving the data itself, not the all system.
For the system, note the version of the [**omnibus package**](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html#consider-the-omnibus-package-installation) you are installing, and you will be able to re-install it in minutes.

> How can I check weather GitLab is installed via omnibus or from source?

See if your gitlab root folder has a .git in it: that would mean it represents a [**clone from the sources**](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html#clone-the-source).

Comment: my system has both  /etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json (for omnibus packages) and /home/git/gitlab/.secret (for installations from source). Now i need to take the backup so which command should i prefer out of the below two

Comment: sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create or sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: I'll check on my instance and get back to you

Comment: iam not able to figure out weather my git was setup from omnibus or from source..my system has configuration files for both the methods..

Comment: another query- do i need to stop unicorn , sidekiq and nginx before taking backup..offical gitlab page does not states that but i got this information in few blogs..